# Chrome Sync Error: Update Sync Passphrase

Tags: google-chrome

I have an issue with Chrome (v20.0) and its Sync feature. Recently, I began seeing an orange exclamation mark next to my wrench icon. When I click the icon I see a line that says "Sync Error: Update Sync passphrase..."

[image: "Sync Error: Update Sync passphrase..."]

Clicking this brings up a window telling me that I have data encrypted with a different version of my Google Account password. None of the last few passwords I've used work for this.

[image: "You already have data that is encrypted using a different version of your Google Account password."]

When I follow the instructions to stop and reset Sync via Google Dashboard, namely to click the "Stop sync and delete data from Google"

[image: "Stop sync and delete data from Google"]

The status changes to "in progress. Please reload..."

[image]

However, after 5-10 minutes, I'm right back at the screen that says

[image: "Stop sync and delete data from Google"]

and my wrench icon *still* has the Sync Error exclamation mark:

[image: WTF?!]

I'm at a loss. I've performed the above steps from each of my computers with the same result each time.

Of note, I'm using 2-step verification and application specific passwords for all my Chrome Sync installs (home laptop, home desktop, work desktop, etc.).

Does anyone have any steps I could try, or a solution that got you out of this same mess?